# Outlook Add-in does not trigger when out is in cache

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto

What I am trying to do is to do is perform an action after a new email is received. I can get this working when I am using the online mode in outlook but not when outlook is in cached mode. The message is not moved otherwise.

I have tried

```
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    outlookNameSpace = this.Application.GetNamespace("MAPI");
    inbox = outlookNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.
            OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);

    items = inbox.Items;
    items.ItemAdd +=
        new Outlook.ItemsEvents_ItemAddEventHandler(Quarantine);
}
```

And

```
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{

    //triggers when new email comes in
    this.Application.NewMail += new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.
ApplicationEvents_11_NewMailEventHandler
(Quarantine);

}
```

I have also tried NewMailEx but cannot get to trigger even if outlook is using the online mode so I have not idea what to do with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to handle the `NewMailEx` event which is fired once for every received item that is processed by Microsoft Outlook. The item can be one of several different item types, for example, `MailItem`, `MeetingItem`, or `SharingItem`. The `EntryIDsCollection` string contains the Entry ID that corresponds to that item. Here is what MSDN states:

> The NewMailEx event fires when a new message arrives in the Inbox and before client rule processing occurs. You can use the Entry ID returned in the EntryIDCollection array to call the [NameSpace.GetItemFromID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.getitemfromid) method and process the item. Use this method with caution to minimize the impact on Outlook performance. However, depending on the setup on the client computer, after a new message arrives in the Inbox, processes like spam filtering and client rules that move the new message from the Inbox to another folder can occur asynchronously. You should not assume that after these events fire, you will always get a one-item increase in the number of items in the Inbox.#

The `ItemAdd` event is fired when one or more items are added to the specified collection. This event does not run when a large number of items are added to the folder at once.

Finally, the signature of `ItemAdd` and `NewMailEx` event handlers is different. You can't use the same function to handle both of them.